# ¿Hay alguna forma de averiguar cuantos y cuales callbaks hay en una collección de delegados del tipo Action?

Tags: c#, delegados

La cuetion es la siguiente. Si yo tengo un action.

```
Action action:
```

Y A este Action le añado unos cuantos manejadores tal que asi:

```
public class Duda
{
 Action action;

 void handler1(){}
 void handler2(){}
 void handler3(){}
 void handler4(){}

 void Init()
{
    action+=handler1;        
    action+=handler3;
}
```

}

Hay alguna fora de saber cuantos y cuales son los elementtos que se han agregado al action en runtime?
Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes el método `GetInvocationList()`. Este es un ejemplo muy simple que puedes compilar y ejecutar:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Action a = ()=>Console.WriteLine("First");
        
        a+=()=>Console.WriteLine("Second");
        
        foreach (Action aa in a.GetInvocationList())
            aa.Invoke();
    }
}
```

El resultado es:

> First
>  Second

Comment: El resultado es un `IEnumerable` para el que tienes extensiones que te permiten explorar su contenido.

Comment: Hola!! Genial!! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!! Perdona la tardanza en responder a tu respuesta últimamente estoy en otro mundo!! XD Un Saludo!!